# How To Create A Test User Which Inherits From User

Tags: django, selenium, functional-testing, django-testing, django-tests

I have the following User types:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    user_type = models.CharField(choices=USER_TYPES, max_length=255, default='student')

class Student(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

When creating a User for a functional test id usually do this:

```
user = get_user_model().objects.create_user(username='test', email='test@example.com', password='passwordtest')
EmailAddress.objects.create(user=user, email="example@example.com", primary=True, verified=True)
```

For this test I need to create a Student, yet cant find any information on how to do this. Everything I try, such as this:

```
user = get_user_model().objects.create_user(username='test', email='test@example.com', password='passwordtest')
user = Student.objects.create(user=user)
```

Results in errors such as this:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1062, "Duplicate entry '1' for key 'user_id'")
```

Thank you.

Comment: have  you overridden save method on user maybe to create Student object or something like that. Post full trackback of error

Comment: Ahh yes, thank you. I created this functionality a while ago and was creating a Student instance using a signal when a User was created.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1062, "Duplicate entry '1' for key 'user_id'")
```

What this means is that your database already contains a student attached to your user with `user.id as 1` (probably with username "test")

You can simply call:

```
student = Student.objects.filter(user__username="test")
print(student)
```

or use `get_or_create` as:

```
student = Student.objects.get_or_create(user__id=1)
print(student)
```

or delete your database and start fresh then call this:

```
user = get_user_model().objects.create_user(username='test', email='test@example.com', password='passwordtest')
user = Student.objects.create(user=user)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I created this functionality a while ago and was creating a Student instance using a signal when a User was created.